# Expose logs in Spring Boot Admin without having log file

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-boot-admin

I am currently using Spring Boot Admin to manage a Spring Boot application. SBA exposes correctly the logs of the application in the tab "Log". As part of transitioning the deployment to Docker I would like to continue forwarding our logs to `stdout` and ELK, but to stop logging to a rotating log file.

After removing from Spring Boot application.properties file the property "logging.file" I could check that, as expected, the rotating log file was not created. However this configuration change had the side-effect of removing from SBA the "Log" tab exposing the logs.

My question is: is there any way I could still expose logs through Spring Boot Admin without having to have a log file for the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot admin needs the logfile acuator endpoint. The endpoint needs a file on the disk. It either serves the file from `loging.file` or `endpoint.logfile.external-file`.

Here is a simple workaround:
Add a link to a kibana query for the application (or similar) to your info endpoint l. It is rendered as hyperlink in SBA. This would be a convenient way for the users to find the log output.

Comment: hi joshiste. What about if I dont have and ELK like kibana? can i do something else?